# what is the source of combobox control name?

Tags: wpf, winforms, user-interface, combobox, terminology

We all know about the combobox control.

I wonder what is the nature of the term?

Is it coming from combination box (text box and drop down list) ;-)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it coming from combination box (text box and drop down list) ;-)?

Yup. Spot on.